# svd value different between matlab 2011b and 2012b

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, svd

i try to implement the same matrix F to the svd function on both versions of matlab.
However, i found out that sign of U and V matrix from both solutions are opposite.
May i know which versions of MATLAB provide a better or more accurate answer?
or actually both answers are correct?

Comment: Both answers are correct and as good as each other. The sign is often different between implementations. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935893/any-reason-why-octave-r-numpy-and-lapack-yield-different-svd-results-on-the-sa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053380/svd-computing-different-result-in-matlab-and-opencv   and http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/297670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular value decomposition of a matrix is only defined up to a sign, so the signs of `U` and `V` are arbitrary, and both answers are correct. Whichever signs MATLAB produces, it should still be the case that `F = U*S*V`, so `U` and `V` constitute a correct singular value decomposition of `F`. (Note "a", not "the").

You shouldn't rely on MATLAB producing particular signs, and it may vary from version to version.